# Неподдерживаемый размер для файла формата BMP

Tags: c, bmp

Я реализовывал консольное приложение, которое принимает на вход картинку формата BMP изменяет её (перекрашивает некоторые пиксели) и выводит её копию. Суть в том, что я помещаю первые 54 байта в буфер bmpHeader, затем копирую и изменяю информацию о пикселях, создаю новый файл, куда записываю bmpHeader и pixelInfo(информацию с перекрашенными пикселями)  `fwrite(bmpHeader, 1, 54, newBMP); fwrite(pixelInfo, 1, height * width * 3, newBMP);` таким образом. Итог такой, что если задать размер исходного BMP файла, например, 101 x 101, то новый файл получиться битым (Windows пишет: "Данный файл не поддерживается"). Хотя при 100 x 100 работает. И ещё есть такая закономерность, что размер mod 4 должен быть равен 0.

Comment: просто длина строки должна быть кратной 4 (в байта). Если это не так, то нужно в конец добавить необходимое кол-во пустых байтов (например, нулей). Называется padding. Если у Вас 101 пиксель и каждый пиксель по 3 байта, то сумарная длина строки - 303 байта.  И нужен один дополнительный байт в конец. Ну и конечно теперь длину файла нужно правильно рассчитать.

Answer (score 0):

Размер заголовка не обязательно 54 байта, он может меняться. Лучше определите, где начинаются пиксельные данные, из поля `bfOffBits`

`height * width * 3` - неверная формула. Правила выравнивания строк требуют, чтобы размер строки был (деление целочисленное)

```
ByteWidth =  (BitsPerPixel * Width + 31) / 32 * 4
```

Так что размер данных

```
ByteWidth * height
```